# Remove any row with empty columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV that looks like:

```
0             Local ID                  Sample ID   Rev Code 
1                    4                       2949  GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG
50                 441                       1057  GGTAGAGACACGAGTCTAGAT
51                                                                      
52                                                                      
53                                                                      
54
```

And I use the following to convert this into a dataframe:

```py
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_to_use.splitlines())
rows = [r for r in reader]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

How can drop the rows where other columns are empty?

I have tried doing `df.dropna(subset=['Rev Code'], inplace=True)` but it returns

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/daudn/Documents/clean_space/env_tgs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4859, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but using `pd.read_csv` might me more useful in general. In this case, you could do something like `rows = [r for r in reader if r]`

Comment: Your list contains only one element. Remove backets and try again.  `df.dropna(subset='Rev Code', inplace=True)`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen I think it is related since pandas has a bunch of helpful inferred types when you load a csv using it.  If loaded with pandas the df.dropna() method would work.  I would highly recommend this over the method used by the OP above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform empty values to NaN (skip if already NaN)

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Then you should be able to do what you where asking:

```
df.dropna(subset=['Rev Code'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to drop rows that are empty is simply:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # read csv
df = df.dropna() # drop empty rows
```

This will return

```
    0   Local ID    Sample ID   Rev Code
0   1   4   2949.0  GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG
1   50  441 1057.0  GGTAGAGACACGAGTCTAGAT
```

In case you only want to delete the rows where `Rev Code` is empty, you can apply this.

```
df =pd.read_csv('test.txt')
df.dropna(subset=['Rev Code'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with **`regex=True`** to replace blanks with `NaN` then you can use [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv') #read csv
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
#if you want select subset
#df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna(subset=['Rev Code'])
```

**note that it's not the same `''` as `' '`**.
That is why it is a good practice to use regex here